# JqMobile table style broken?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have problem with my table JqMobile style is not working when I uploaded to the server I want datat be horizontal not broken.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tbu9U/
[image]
html

```
    <table data-role="table" id="productOrders" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-table ui-table-reflow">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Code</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Qty.</th>
         <th>Ext.</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Code</b></td>
         <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Name</b></td>
         <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Price</b></td>
         <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Qty.</b></td>
         <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Ext.</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>uj7uu</td>
         <td>games</td>
         <td class="dollars">$70</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>$210</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The html is correct. You could have a not closing tag issue, but you should check the code before and after the table.

Comment: I don't know it still apply the style I upload my code to Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tbu9U/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fiddle updated:  **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Tbu9U/1/**

The only change was on the table markup, remove the class ui-table-reflow and instead add ui-responsive:

```
<table data-role="table" id="productOrders" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-table ui-responsive">
```